# When I create new .net core web api its output type is displaying as console application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, webapi

As you can see in picture under properties output type is console Application 
[image]

How does it affects on api  do I need to change that to deploy on IIS??

Comment: Most .NET Core project types (ASP.NET Core, unit testing) are console based, and nothing is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think every .net core application is a console application but is configured under the program.cs file to run as a web app in your case web api

Answer (score 1):

No!! leave it as a Console app. 
when you publish your web API in IIS it will create web.config
open it there will be a path for your *.exe

For more info -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#webconfig-file

Guide to host .net core app in IIS -> https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/23/hosting-an-asp-net-core-web-application-in-iis/